# JSON vs. JavaScript object array. Why is the second approach different in result than the first? And how to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, object

I know this is NOT a valid JSON, but when I declare this as variable directly within my code, then I can use it as an object.

```
<script>
//  this will result in object
    var mydata = {
        users: [{
            person: {
                firstName: "Garry",
                lastName: "Finch"
            },
            jobTitle: "Front End Technical Lead",
            twitter: "gazraa"
        }, {
            person: {
                firstName: "Hans",
                lastName: "Wurst"
            },
            jobTitle: "Photographer",
            twitter: "photobasics"
        }, {
            person: {
                firstName: "Paul",
                lastName: "Stark"
            },
            jobTitle: "LEGO Geek",
            twitter: "minifigures"
        }]
    };

    console.log('mydata: ' + mydata);
    console.log(mydata);
</script>
```

[image: console.log result]

now I would like to store the same information into a file "table.data.js".
the file then looks like: (the inner of BEGIN and END)

```
//BEGIN
{
    users: [{
        person: {
            firstName: "Garry",
            lastName: "Finch"
        },
        jobTitle: "Front End Technical Lead",
        twitter: "gazraa"
    }, {
        person: {
            firstName: "Hans",
            lastName: "Wurst"
        },
        jobTitle: "Photographer",
        twitter: "photobasics"
    }, {
        person: {
            firstName: "Paul",
            lastName: "Stark"
        },
        jobTitle: "LEGO Geek",
        twitter: "minifigures"
    }]
}
//END
```

then I have tried different ways to read this file

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Content/modules/Controls/table/table.data.js",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var json = data;
        console.log(json);
    }
});
```

then tried with $.get and $.getScript
in any case the result would be not the same object

```
//var jqxhr = $.get("Content/modules/Controls/table/table.data.js", function () {
var jqxhr = $.getScript("Content/modules/Controls/table/table.data.js", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        console.log("success");
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        testdata = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(testdata);
  }).fail(function () {
      console.log("error");
  }).always(function () {
      console.log("finished");
  });
```

The result would never be the same object. I am only able to log the data as "plain" text into console.
I guess this is a small step for some with knowledge, but actually for me a book with seven seals.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all the responses.
In summary that means, it is NOT possible to load the external data, store it in a variable like "mydata" and then work the same way as declaring it directly within the code? I will change the data to a valid JSON then.

Then I would give @Quentin the medal for the shortest precise answer.
But,thanks all for your clarification.

Comment: Just store it as `var mydata = {
        users: [{
            person: {...` and load it as `<script src="mydata.js"></script>` or using getScript or using the add-to-head method

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` claims you are SENDING JSON, but you aren't sending anything. Get rid of that.

Comment: Try putting all keys in the js-file between double quotes, e.g. `"users": [{ "person": {` etc

Comment: In *Javascript*, both `{ foo: 'bar' }` and `{"foo": "bar"}` are valid. *JSON* is a subset of Javascript syntax, defining a text format to express arbitrary values, and in JSON the latter form is the only allowable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is not valid JSON (because you aren't quoting your property names).

Your file is not valid JavaScript (because you can't have an object literal floating in the middle of nowhere, you need (for example) an assignment to the left of it).

You should change the file so it is either valid JSON or valid JavaScript (preferably the former).

Comment: I am aware of it, but what if I am not able to edit the external js file? Thanks for your comment @Quentin

Comment: Then you're using a non-standard data format and should consider writing a custom parser for it. (You'd be better off finding a way to get the data file changed).

Comment: @MattOpen optionally, if you must have the file representation as a JS object, you could use `eval` on the string representation to execute it as JS in the required context. However, this is discouraged in most cases as it leaves your application open to attack

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a serialized representation of hierarchical data. What that means is it's essentially a way to store a hierarchical structure (like an object) as a string which can be serialised (and sent over the network, for example).

If you are storing the file as a JS Object as in the structure you have shown in the question, you will need to invoke that file as another script which either sets that data as a global or exposes a function which you can invoke to return the data. You can then use that data in your other files which has access to the same scope.

```
<script src='./path/to/data.js'></script>
<script>
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

And in your data.js file:

```
data =     {
    users: [{
        person: {
            firstName: "Garry",
            lastName: "Finch"
        },
        jobTitle: "Front End Technical Lead",
        twitter: "gazraa"
    }, {
        person: {
            firstName: "Hans",
            lastName: "Wurst"
        },
        jobTitle: "Photographer",
        twitter: "photobasics"
    }, {
        person: {
            firstName: "Paul",
            lastName: "Stark"
        },
        jobTitle: "LEGO Geek",
        twitter: "minifigures"
    }]
};
```

If you want to use a JSON file, your file needs to look like this:

```
{
    "users": [
    {
        "person": {
        "firstName": "Garry",
        "lastName": "Finch"
        },
        "jobTitle": "Front End Technical Lead",
        "twitter": "gazraa"
    },
    {
        "person": {
        "firstName": "Hans",
        "lastName": "Wurst"
        },
        "jobTitle": "Photographer",
        "twitter": "photobasics"
    },
    {
        "person": {
        "firstName": "Paul",
        "lastName": "Stark"
        },
        "jobTitle": "LEGO Geek",
        "twitter": "minifigures"
    }
    ]
}
```

The main difference being that the object keys are in quotes. To get this representation, you can call `JSON.stringify(data)` (where data is some JS object) in your console which will return a JSON string.

If your file is like this, you can use AJAX as shown in your question and retrieve the data in that manner. Based on the AJAX library you are using, it may even automatically do `JSON.parse` for you based on the response header content-type value. (I think jQuery does this for you)

Comment: upvote for clarification and possible solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all keys in the js-file between double quotes, e.g. `"users": [{ "person": {` etc.

Even though it looks like javascript, JSON is a **data format** and as such has its own rules.